# Convert folder of word docs into a single, parseable spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Is it possible to show MSWord a folder full of .docs or .docxs and have it convert them into a spreadsheet containing columns for different variables that describe each document, such as filename, date created, body content etc. with the end goal in this case being to iterate over the spreadsheet ?

Critical that the actual contents of the files are included too.

(or indeed, can any other office suite do this ?)

Comment: Yes, this is possible. However, it's hard for us to come up with a solution that would work for you considering we don't know what the contents of the .docs are.. What's your goal? Why are you trying to do this? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Here's one quick way:

1. Open a windows CMD window.
2. type:
    dir directory\directory > temp.txt   (ex: dir "c:\text\my msword stuff"   > temp.txt)
3. In Excel, use the data tab and import the file as "from text".
4. Use the "fixed width" formatting option to adjust the columns as
   needed.

Result looks like this: (The top lines would need to be tweaked by hand or deleted)
[image]

Comment: would this include the content of the word files too ?

Comment: No, I missed that you wanted the content. Since the content could be huge, not sure how you would want to present it in a list like this. One option would be to write an excel macro to use each filename (in the spreadsheet) as a link to open the file. All Office apps can embed other Office apps as objects, so there are hooks for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Word-documents are actually archives with a lot of stuff in it, so if you want the content you need something that interprets that, like Word. I don't know of any program that does what you need.
Another option is writing something yourself in either VBA or VB.Net/C#, though that would be a bit of work.